# Provisioning profile "Development XXX" doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Development: Noorul(TXNRY2JRLN)"

Tags: swift, xcode, ipa

I am creating the build with Generic iOS Device. When i try to build the .IPA file, it's showing the error (Provisioning profile "Development XXX" doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Development: Noorul(TXNRY2JRLN)")under the `Signing & Capabilities` Tab.

When i go to `Build Settings` tab.then i can see the Signing certificate. then Why it's showing an error.

I am new to iOS Development.

Kindly help me.

I am herewith attached the screenshot of the image

[image]

i think, it shows proper signing certification under the provisioning profile.

So,The keychain doesn't have any problem.

[image]

Comment: please check again buildsetting-> signing and code signing identity and set a particular certificate for debug.

Comment: This development provisioning profile contains development certificate in it. Do you have that certificate in your keychain? Please let me know if you don't understand my words as you are new in iOS Development.

Comment: You can try with Signing as Automatically manage signing.

Comment: @Rameez i have updated the image which shows the key chain information. Kindly take look into it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**2023 UPDATE: XCODE 15**

Follow these steps to edit your provisioning profile and certificate.

1. Login and goto https://developer.apple.com/account/
2. Select **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles**
3. From left side panel, select **Profiles**
4. Select the provisioning profile you are using and click to open it.
5. select the Edit button **Generate a Provisioning Profile** page
6. At the bottom, you can see the list of certificates.
7. Select the one that is installed in your Keychain and click SAVE.
8. Download the new provisioning profile and double click on it to save in keychain.
9. Now check your Xcode, your new provisioning profile will start showing up. Select it and the error will go.

Comment: i will try your solution. give me some time.

Comment: after i did it, it says, Missing private key for signing certificate. Failed to locate the private key matching "Apple development: XXX" (TNxYRJ2RLN) in the keychain. to sign with this signing certificate, install its private key in your keychain. if you don't have the private key, select a different signing certificate for CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY in the build settings editor.

Comment: Create a new iOS app development certificate then and also create a new provisioning profile

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Delete all certificates in keychain access-login, delete all related keys in keys tab.
2. Delete target certificate from certificates apple.dev.
3. Go to XCode and choose the provisioning profile, an error “your profile don't have a certificate” will appear.
4. Click choose certificate and in the bottom on the + choose your certificate to create.
5. Now go to apple.dev-profiles-click the profile-edit- choose the new certificate.

Comment: I concur only after creating a certificate using Xcode, and then assigning it to the prov. profile in developer account on Apple, Xcode magically accepted the profile. When certificate was created in dev account on Apple - Xcode was saying "missing certificate". Must be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Apple Developer website [certificates](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list)
2. Make sure your certificate is created using the CSR created from your machine. If not, consider recreating it.
3. Download your certificate and double click it to install it in your system.
4. Go to [profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list) and make sure it is created using the specific certificate installed in your system. If not you can edit the profile and choose the exact certificate.
5. Download and install the profile.
6. If the error is still showing, quit and re-open X-Code.